# Errormessage while playing .wma in clementine: "Could not demultiplex stream."

Tags: sound, music, error-handling, clementine

Me and my *clementine 1.2.3* on *Kubuntu 14.04* again... ;/
This time it's about a **.wma** audio file. Clementine plays it half and then shows the following **error**:

[image: sorry for the german]

Which translates to `Could not demultiplex stream.`

The error is reproducible with **5 completely dirrefent wma's** so far.

**Konsole**-Error:

```
08:35:13.289 ERROR GstEnginePipeline:562            1 "gstasfdemux.c(1692): gst_asf_demux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin-0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstASFDemux:asfdemux0:
Error parsing ASF packet 237" 
08:35:13.289 WARN  GstEngine:572                    Gstreamer error: "Der Datenstrom konnte nicht demultiplext werden." 
08:35:13.289 ERROR logging:55                       Source ID 13 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

following pakages are **already installed**:

```
wajig listinstalled gstreamer0.10
gstreamer0.10-alsa:amd64
gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg:amd64
gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3:amd64
gstreamer0.10-nice:amd64
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad:amd64
gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:amd64
gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:amd64
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly:amd64
gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:amd64
gstreamer0.10-qapt
gstreamer0.10-x:amd64
libgstreamer0.10-0:amd64
libgstreamer0.10-0:i386
```

I also tried to **delete that .bin file** in the hidden folder.

Comment: Try another WMA. I think, your WMA is broken.

Comment: how to fix broken wma's? Do you think convert by clementine to mp3 will work?

Comment: Tried another WMA. Same.

Comment: The error message translates to "Could not demultiplex stream." Source: https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/gstreamer0.10/+pots/gstreamer-0.10/de/+translate?start=52 (link is probably approximate).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/577691/how-to-fix-could-not-demultiplex-stream-on-video-playback

Comment: @zulu34sx You can run a program with its language temporarily set to English by executing it with the environment  variable `LANG=C` set. Example: `LANG=C clementine` This is useful for pasting outputs or screenshots to English support forums or Q&A sites like AskUbuntu.com!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the bug report at https://github.com/clementine-player/clementine/issues/3593 a workaround is to uncheck `Save statistics in file tags when possible`.

A fix was committed in July 2014 so upgrading to a newer version may help as well.  If not, maybe download the latest bleeding-edge sources and build them (but be aware that they may contain new and interesting bugs).

Comment: not a fix but a workaround... when there is news please contact me, since i want to use that feature writing the statistics in the file.

Comment: The fixed version will most likely ever be available in Ubuntu 14.04. Find and install a backport which has the fix, or upgrade to a nower Ubuntu version which has it.

Comment: See also https://launchpad.net/clementine - newer Ubuntu versions seem to have version 1.2.3 but it's not clear to me whether it contains the fix. Maybe simply try to install the version from a newer release (and hope its dependency requirements aren't too different; requiring a newer `libc6` in particular usually means forget it).

Comment: i AM using 1.2.3.